# Running wxPython module on Windows XP?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a Python project that uses the wxPython module but the problem is that I don't have any idea why isn't working.

I tried to run it on Windows 10 (School) and it runs fine but when I try to run it at home with my Windows XP it doesn't run. The main problem is that it doesn't say any problem, it just seems to run but it doesn't.

I am using Python 2.7 and I am not running the .exe file from the application I just run the .py file that executes everything. (I did in the same way in both Operating systems)

I have installed wxPython 4.0.2.

Is that I am missing something??

I am new in this, so pls don't be so hard!

Comment: try to run it in a console and post the exception. Else we cannot help you, _ever_

Comment: (we're running wxPython on windows XP 32 bit / 64 bit on Python 2.7 so it's possible!)

Comment: we run windows xp and wxpython as well ... no problems ... nothing magic

Comment: Okey, I will try again today too see which exception reports console!

Thanks so much for the moment!

PD: Srry for the English!